# Manual Subscriptions not being called

Tags: knockout.js

If a dependent observable is changed in a manual subscription, shouldn't that change trigger any other subscriptions that are based on the observable?

In the example below, a change to the `selectedGroupType` property changes the `selectedTravellerCount` which should then cause the `selectedTravellerCount` subscription to trigger. This doesnt happen though.

```
viewModel.selectedGroupType.subscribe(function(groupType) {
    alert(groupType);
    this.selectedTravellerCount = 10;
}, viewModel);

viewModel.selectedTravellerCount.subscribe(function(travellerCount) {
    alert(this.travellerCount);
}, viewModel);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `selectedTravellerCount` is an observable, then you need to set the value like:

```
this.selectedTravellerCount(10);
```